# how to pass "keys[posting] = value" in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

how to pass field in retrofit like this :

keys[posting]:value

keys[posting] is a fieldname and posting is value of keys.

pass object class in @Body Parameter  retrofit like this :

```
public class Vote{
    int id;
    String keys;

    public Vote(int id,String keys){
        this.id = id;
        this.keys = keys
    }
   }
```

while pass this object it will give output like this :

```
{"id":1,"keys":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

but i want like this :

```
{"id":1,"keys[posting]":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: Try `@SerializedName("keys[posting]")` annotation.